# Flash stopped playing sound

Tags: 12.04, sound, flash

my ubuntu stopped playing sound. I tried to search what I am using as sound device , but the system manager just says "built in audio"

Can you please direct me what should I try?

So far I only tried the flash settings and verified that Ubuntu can play sound using flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found an answer:

1. Play flash with sound in FF - no sound
2. Flash in Chrome was ok, so I knew something was bad in the FF
3. Play flash with sound again
4. Right click volume icon in top right corner (Unity)
5. Sound Settings - Tab Applications
6. Check that all applications are on max volume

They were not in my own case. I had no idea there is app seeting for volume ... now I know :)